# What SqlDbType maps to varBinary(max)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, types

What SqlDbType maps to varBinary(max)? SqlDbType.VarBinary says that it is limited to 8K. SQL Server documentation says that varbinary(max) can store aprrox. 2GB. But SqlDbType.VarBinary says that it is limited to 8K.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

SqlDbType.VarBinary with length -1 is the equivalent of VARBINARY(MAX), at least in theory. But the problem is a bit more complex, as there is also a type (not an enum value), namely [`SqlTypes.SqlBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlbytes.aspx) which can be used. And there is [`SqlTypes.SqlFileStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlfilestream.aspx) which can be used also for `VARBINARY(MAX)` types, when they have the `FILESTREAM` attribute.

But the problem is that none of these enums or types cover the real issue with working with `VARBINARY(MAX)` columns in ADO.Net: memory consumption. All these types, when used 'out-of-the-box', will create copies of the value allocated as a single array in memory, which is at best unperformant, but as content gets larger becomes down right impossible to use because allocation failures. I have a couple of articles that show the proper way to handle `VARBINARY(MAX)` values in ADO.Net using streaming semantics that avoid the creation of in-memory copies of the entire content:

- [Download and Upload images from SQL Server via ASP.Net MVC](http://rusanu.com/2010/12/28/download-and-upload-images-from-sql-server-with-asp-net-mvc/)
- [FILESTREAM MVC: Download and Upload images from SQL Server](http://rusanu.com/2011/02/06/filestream-mvc-download-and-upload-images-from-sql-server/)

Comment: Really strange that the above did not work for me. I had to write: dtProducts.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Cover", typeof(byte[])) { AllowDBNull = true }); notice the byte[]...this is what worked for me.

Comment: Misread this at first.  First sentence should be "with  length set to  -1".  Didn't solve my issue but good to know.  Also there is a SqlType for varbinary now (2022): SqlDbType.VarBinary.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
SqlParameter blobParam = new SqlParameter("@blob", SqlDbType.VarBinary, buffer.Length);
blobParam.Value = buffer;
cmd.Parameters.Add(blobParam);
```

See if that works

Comment: what was the solution, just out of curiousity?

Comment: What is the type of `buffer`?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Although not the author, I've encountered a buffer when working with SqlGeometry. You can get SqlBytes out of the SqlGeometry type, so in my case the preceding lines would read something like:

System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlBytes sqlBytes = sqlGeo.STAsBinary();
byte[] buffer = sqlBytes.Buffer;

Comment: Thanks, @StuartQ, but that doesn't tell me the .NET type of `buffer`.

Comment: @JohnSaunders It's byte[].  Should be showing in my latest edit.

Comment: @JohnSaunders the SqlParameter constructor takes a size argument (int) so I assume buffer is a byte array

Comment: Could you pass "-1" instead of buffer.length.  Where -1 implies "max" (2Gbytes?).  If buffer is a byte-array (variable length?) rather than a fixed length buffer?  [I am trying to read a varbinary from DB that I already wrote to DB.]

Answer (score 0):

This might help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1904w6t.aspx

As ugly as it might be, SqlDbType.Image appears to be the way to go. Looks like I need to update my ORM, since anything over 8k would currently break it.