# Images Created with C# - How to Insert them in BLOB via SQL

Tags: c#, sql, blob

Let's say if I capture a screen shot. There is my code for it

```
int sWidth = 1600, sHeight = 1200;

Bitmap B_M_P = Bitmap(sWidth, sHeight);

Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage((Image)B_M_P);
gfx.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, new Size(screenWidth, screenHeight));            

B_M_P.Save("img.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

instead of saving this to an Image, i wanna be able to send this to my SQL or MySQL and store them in the database as BLOB.

i know the `LINQ` as well to query the DB. What i don't know is the intermediate portion.

- What kind of `Data Type` will be used to INSERT in a BLOB column, my
  guess is it will be a `Byte[]`?

if it is a 'Byte', then the conversion is pretty easy.

```
ImageConverter imgc = new ImageConverter();
Byte[] temp = (byte[])imgc.ConvertTo(B_M_P,typeof(byte[]));
```

so that afterwards i can prepare my query

```
"INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (pic) VALUES ('"+temp+"');"
```

- If not then **WHAT IS THE TYPE** & **HOW TO CONVERT**

Comment: That method of inserting data is very **VERY** wrong, You should be using [Prameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx). If you do it the way you want to it opens your self to exploitation. Even if your case this time would not likely allow it to happen it is a VERY bad habit to get. When you hear about "SQL Injection attacks" writing queries like you did is what causes it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your are correct that you just need to turn it in to a byte array. The datatype of your table should be [VarBinary(max)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362.aspx).

Note that there is a [Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx) datatype, but that datatype will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server, so Microsoft is recommending everyone switch to VarBinary for future compatibility.

---

BLOBs and VarBinary(max) are the same thing. From [Understanding VARCHAR(MAX) in SQL Server 2005](http://www.teratrax.com/articles/varchar_max.html)

> To solve this problem, Microsoft introduced the VARCHAR(MAX), 
>   NVARCHAR(MAX), and VARBINARY(MAX) data types in SQL Server 2005. These
>   data types can hold the same amount of data BLOBs can hold (2 GB) and
>   they are stored in the same type of data pages used for other data
>   types. When data in a MAX data type exceeds 8 KB, an over-flow page is
>   used. SQL Server 2005 automatically assigns an over-flow indicator to
>   the page and knows how to manipulate data rows the same way it
>   manipulates other data types. You can declare variables of MAX data
>   types inside a stored procedure or function and even pass them as
>   variables. You can also use them inside string functions.
>
> Microsoft recommend using MAX data types instead of BLOBs in SQL Server 2005. In fact, BLOBs are being deprecated in future releases of
>   SQL Server.

That `Image` data type I mentioned at the top is a example of the old-style BLOB datatype.

---

Here is a example of how the code should be

```
using(var cmd = SqlCommand("INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (pic) VALUES (@pic);", connection)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@pic", temp);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

However there are some Gotchas if you are working with large files, see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5827110/80274) and its links for in depth look at storing large data objects in the database.

Comment: there is problem, the data type of my table is BLOB, cuz i have some tutorial which will teach me how to retrieve images when they are saved in BLOB, so should i stick with BLOB or try to do it via VarBinary

Comment: i remember seeing a question here on stackoverflow, to blob or not

Comment: @JunaidSaeed Your tutorial will work fine with varbinary(max).

Comment: Looks like the database is MySQL and not MSSQL, see [PHP retrieve VARBINARY & display as an image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9440759/php-retrieve-varbinary-display-as-an-image)