# Failed to convert parameter value from a Byte[] to a String

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, string, byte

I'm building an app with c# asp.net. I need to insert some data into database. Everything works fine, but i get problem with inserting an image.

My database table:

**Order**

```
OrderID int
description varchar(50)
numOfItems int
material varchar(50)
image varbinary(max)
```

**My code for inserting data into database**

```
protected void btnAddItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filepath = fileUpload.PostedFile.FileName;
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(filepath);
        string ext = Path.GetExtension(filename);
        string contentType = String.Empty;

        switch (ext)
        {
            case ".jpg":
                contentType = "image/jpg";
                break;
            case ".png":
                contentType = "image/png";
                break;
            case ".gif":
                contentType = "image/gif";
                break;
            case ".pdf":
                contentType = "application/pdf";
                break;
        }
        if (contentType != String.Empty)
        {
            Stream fs = fileUpload.PostedFile.InputStream;
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
            Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);

            string kon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mk"].ConnectionString;

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(kon))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Order(description, numOfItems, material, image"))
                {
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", inputTextArea.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numOfItems", inputTextArea.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@material", inputTextArea.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@image", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = bytes;
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    Response.Write("Success!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When i do that, i get the following error : **Failed to convert parameter value from a Byte[] to a String.**

Any ideas?

**UPDATE - new error**

Incorrect syntax near 'image '. error. any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824620/what-sqldbtype-maps-to-varbinarymax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the parameter `@image` the passed value is a byte array but you ware specified  that the input will be `VarChar` change it to `Binary`. so the statement that add specific parameter will be looks like the following

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@image", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = bytes;
```

And you have to add the placeholders to your query, which means the query text should be like this:

```
"INSERT INTO Order(description, numOfItems, material, image)values(@description, @numOfItems,@material,@image)"
```

Comment: actually now i get  Incorrect syntax near 'image '. error. any ideas?

Comment: @fokz8 : You have to add placeholders to the query, check the updates in my answer

Comment: that seems to solve that problem. but yet again i get another one...i also have "OrderID" as my primary key, but i didn't want to put it into my webform. So how do i create and input id, without user inputting it? btw, i get this error = "annot insert the value NULL into column 'OrderID', table '.dbo.Order'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails."

Comment: Make the column `OrderID` as auto increment in the table. so it will automatically updates as you inserted each row

Comment: Coool..! Always happy to help you

Answer (score 2):

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@image", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = bytes;
```

Your image is not of type `VarChar` you need to fix that. Most likely, you need `Binary`.

Comment: actually now i get  Incorrect syntax near 'image '. error. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Change the `SqlDbType` based on your database column type :

Possible datatypes for saving images in SQL are :

String types:

Data types and  Description :

**binary(n)**   Fixed width binary string. Maximum 8,000 bytes

**varbinary**   Variable width binary string. Maximum 8,000 bytes

**varbinary(max)**  Variable width binary string. Maximum 2GB

**image**   Variable width binary string. Maximum 2GB

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@image", SqlDbType.image).Value = bytes;
```

or

```
// Replace 8000, below, with the correct size of the field
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@image", SqlDbType.VarBinary, 8000).Value = bytes;
```

Modify your SQL Command to :

```
SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Order(description, numOfItems, material, image) values (@description,@numOfItems,@material,@image)")
```

Comment: actually now i get  Incorrect syntax near 'image '. error. any ideas?

Comment: what modification you did before getting this incorrect syntax error ?

Comment: think there is problem with my insert statement, as break point gets past image part

Comment: @fokz8 : yes definitely, you missed the place holders, check the updates in my answer

Comment: I've added the sql command , you have to replace your sql command , I've added

Comment: @AlinaAnjum : it wont compile, check the syntax errors

Comment: Thanks @un-lucky :)

Comment: cooll.......! we are all here to help others, so happy to help you as well