# Inserting Image to MS SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, image, xamarin.android

I am trying to insert a image to my online database but on insertion the database closes my connection during the execution. I have tested other insert statements with other tables on the same database and works fine.  I have tried changing the database type to varbinary(MAX) and image. Still the same error. 
My image is getting saved in a `byte []` variable and then inserted with AddWithValue.

Here is my code to convert a signature to a `byte []`:

```
var signatureImage = sig.GetImage();

        byte[] bitmapData;
        using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            signatureImage.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 50, memStream);
            bitmapData = memStream.ToArray();
        }
```

Here is my code for adding into a parameter for my SQL command:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@waiverSigned", user.waiverSigned);
```

The Error I am getting:
 `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Server closed the connection.`

Environment: Xamarin Android

Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Have you tried to specify parameter type as varbinary? - [see example here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1088630/5331361)

Comment: @DenisKrasakov I just tried that and still giving me the same error. I am wondering if its to much data on one thread (UI Thread). We tried inserting just a byte array and a number to newly created table and it worked. So I wonder if its too much on one thread.

Comment: Maybe something here would help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824620/what-sqldbtype-maps-to-varbinarymax

Comment: @ZLK This doesn't solve my issue. I open the connection, I use `ExecuteNonQuery()` but during that query an error is thrown saying `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Server closed the connection.`

Comment: Generally it is bad practice to use database directly from mobile client. I suggest to make small REST service that handle image uploading and other stuff. But if you want to use database command directly try to increase timeouts for connection and command